# are there cases where MongoDB is really not suited?

Tags: mongodb

I am sorry if this is not a constructive enough question.. Coming from the SQL world I'm just trying to wrap my head around this. After reading a lot about MongoDB, I've become very enthusiastic about it and consider using it for an upcoming application (in combination with Meteor).

However, I came across [this blog post](http://www.sarahmei.com/blog/2013/11/11/why-you-should-never-use-mongodb/), which describes the troubles Diaspora ran into when using it and states `"you should never use MongoDB"`. The examples she's giving sound pretty convincing.

Are these true problems with MongoDB, or were they using it wrong? Is this article now outdated and are there better ways for doing what they're doing (duplicate data for instance, like users being linked to each other, to posts and to comments, is a very common use case)?

Comment: Very very opinion based question, but I think the article is a classic case of "we chose to use it for what it wasn't good at, so the database is at error", aka "aspirin didn't cure my cold".

Comment: Well, in the conclusion she does state that the error was theirs, and that there are use cases for MongoDB as well. However, the title of the article is "why you should never use MongoDB" so that makes her opinion pretty clear :P

Comment: And to be clear, I am **not** asking for opinions, but if the 'facts' as presented in the article can be debunked!

Comment: I can't find any obvious inaccuracies in the article. MongoDB is definitely not intended as a 1:1 replacement for a large scale graph- or relational database. I see many systems that try to do the reverse too, use MySQL as a document database which works just as badly.

Comment: https://github.com/awatson1978/meteor-cookbook/blob/master/cookbook/datalayer.md is pretty adamant about never using SQL. At the bottom, it states that if you need a JOIN, your design is off. So how do you handle if an item in your data set is used in two or more places? Does this automatically mean you need a relational DB?

Comment: Of course that's not means that you need relational DB, but if there is a lot of such places, and you feel like this is a still best design for the problem - that it's mean that you need relational DB. So there is always a question of choice and some kind of trade-off. And you just always select variant who will give you lot, asking for less.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a plenty of cases when `mongodb` not feet good, some of them are

1. When data perfectly described with 'table' metaphor (better using
   `SQL`)
2. When you need `ACID` and `transactions` out of the box
3. When your workflow extremely oriented to `write` operation
4. When you need to generate complex cross-data reports
5. Data model have strongly relational view (a lot of connected
   instances)

There is a lot of others, but this is just something which comes to my head fast.

Comment: Please don't answer questions that are solely based on opinions. It does not help anyone.

Comment: Time to walk away. There's no need to argue in the comments here.